# cannot start postgres - not able to create lockfile

Tags: postgresql, manjaro

I have installed postgres from pacman repo on Manjaro but am running into trouble trying to get it to start.

I have followed the instructions from the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PostgreSQL#Upgrading_PostgreSQL) and have created my db. `initdb -D /var/lib/postgres/data/`

I run the following command but doesn't complete. `pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgres/data/ -l logfile start`

The logfile error is `FATAL:  could not create lock file "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": No such file or directory`

Could someone please explain what this error means and how I can get Postgres to start?

Comment: if it still happens to you [see](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/32154)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have followed the instructions from the arch wiki and have created
> my db.
> initdb -D /var/lib/postgres/data/

The `/run/postgresql` directory does not exist at this point because it's created by the last step of the instructions that you probably overlooked:

> **Finally, start and enable the postgresql.service.**

which means to run `systemctl start postgresql` and `systemctl enable postgresql`

What is misleading is this last part of the output from initdb:

```
Success. You can now start the database server using:

    pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgres/ -l logfile start
```

This advice must be ignored when you're using `systemctl` to manage postgresql as a system service. It is the system service that will take care of creating `/run/postgresql` with the proper permissions and then run the `pg_ctl` command with the proper arguments and paths.

Comment: was exactly that combined with my tired mind trying to run systemctl as the postgres user

Answer (score 0):

When systemd is used, it is specifically **systemd-tmpfiles** that takes care of creating `/run/postgresql` and setting permissions on it.

The systemd-tmpfiles service is part of systemd, and it is responsible for creating and deleting temporaray and volatile files (in `/run`, `/var/run`, `/tmp`, `/var/tmp` etc.). The service is started during boot. You may want to check the man page for `tmpfiles.d` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1** (By managing temporary directory /run/postgresql, /var/run/postgresql)

> Directory */run/postgresql* is a temporary directory. Path
> */var/run/postgresql* is usually a symbolic link to /run/postgresql.
>
> **systemd-tmpfiles** is mechanism to manage such temporary files and directories. **systemd-tmpfiles** creates temporary directories during
> boot and sets their owner, group and permissions.  It may read configuration files in three different locations. Files in
> /etc/tmpfiles.d override files with the same name in
> /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d and /run/tmpfiles.d.

We can create directory */run/postgresql* on the fly at boot time using **systemd-tmpfiles** mechanism by creating postgresql configuration file as below

```
echo "d /run/postgresql 0755 postgres postgres -" > /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/postgresql.conf
```

**Solution 2** (By relocating PostgreSQL lock file location)

> Another way to fix the issue is to relocate the PostgreSQL lock file
> location. We can do so by using below query

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET unix_socket_directories='<any-existing-path-with-valid-permissions>, /tmp';
```

Here we can provide any path for PostgreSQL lock file which is already present on the system and have required permissions to manage lock files by postgres user.